# CrystalReports.NET - varbinary blob

Tags: .net, image, crystal-reports, blob

what's the proper way to display an image (bitmap) stored in sqlserver 2008 database as an varbinary(max) datatype in CrystalReports for .NET?

I have added a 'blobfieldobject' item in crystal reports & it is bound to a datatable with the column of type 'varbinary(max)' but the image won't show up instead a dark background is diplayed.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the image was not being saved in a proper way to the database using the Picturebox control.

Comment: Do not use font 'Calibri', it doesn't render well.